# Django | Generate Total Price from Price per Item and Amount?

Tags: python, django, forms, view, model

im new to Django and im playing a bit around.
So i want to create a Model Field that is dynamicly showing the total price generated from the Amount and Item Price given by the User. Is there a way to do this easy? I would love to find out how that works.

Comment: You don't need a model field for that. Just calculate it through a property, or `.annotate`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a model field for that. You can create a method to do that for you.
In your models.py, you can write a function like this inside the class of your model.

```
def total_price(self):
    return self.price * self.quantity
```

In your HTML templates, you can get the total price by doing something like:

`<p>Price ${{item.total_price}}</p>`